# Need to adjust ordering of subgroups on geom_bar plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, visualization, geom-bar

Need some help trying to order the individual bars on this plot so that they are in the same order in both the "Pre-innoculation" and "Post-innoculation" category. I have tried manually setting the levels for the disease.state vector in both the ggplot code and the line creating the dataframe itself. Not sure why I'm having such trouble with this. Thank you greatly!

```
df.graph1 <- data.frame(
  exp.period = factor(c("Pre-innoculation", "Pre-innoculation", "Pre-innoculation", "Post-innoculation", "Post-innoculation", "Post-innoculation"), levels=c("Pre-innoculation", "Post-innoculation")),
  disease.state = factor(c("Apparent", "Possible", "NA", "Apparent", "Possible", "NA"), levels = c("NA", "Possible", "Apparent")),
  count = factor(c(3, 12, 15, 11, 18, 9),))

ggplot(df.graph1, aes(x=factor(exp.period, level=c('Pre-innoculation', 'Post-innoculation')), y=count, fill=disease.state)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  xlab("Experimental Period") + 
  ylab("") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Disease State"))
```

Comment: Your problem is likely `count = factor(c(3, 12, 15, 11, 18, 9),))`. Count should not be a factor. Just `count = c(3, 12, 15, 11, 18, 9)` will do fine.

Comment: Also note that in your current plot the y-axis goes from 3 to 9 to 11. Clearly not right. Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df.graph1$disease.state=factor(df.graph1$disease.state,levels = c("NA","Possible","Apparent"),ordered = T) #set order of bars

df.graph1$observations=as.numeric(as.character(df.graph1$count)) #convert count to numeric (try what happens, if you only convert to numeric, without converting to character first)

ggplot(df.graph1, aes(x=exp.period, y=observations,
                      fill=disease.state)) + 
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(), colour="black") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  xlab("Experimental Period") + 
  ylab("") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Disease State"))
```